# Wordpress plugin form issue

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress plug in development. I have designed a search form however I have no idea where to handle and print the submitted form data. 
it is a wedget based plug in and the plugin form section code is here:

```
   function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    extract( $args );
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
                $message = apply_filters( 'widget_content', $instance['content'] );
        echo $before_widget;
        //if ( $title )
        //  echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
        echo '<div class="shk_location_form_holder">
                    <span class="shk_loc_title">'.$title.'
                    <form mthod="post">
                    <input type="text" name="shk_inp_search_locations" id="shk_inp_search_locations" /><br>
                    <div style="height:5px"></div>
                    <input type="submit" Value="Search Locations" />
                    </form></div>';
        echo $after_widget;
                if(isset($_REQUEST['shk_inp_search_locations'])){
                    add_filter('the_content','handle_content');
                }
    }
```

Comment: You're form is missing an _action_ parameter. Either you send it to another .php file, leave the action blank and handle the $_POST data in the same page/file/widget or use [AJAX](http://www.askaboutphp.com/213/php-and-jquery-submit-a-form-without-refreshing-the-page.html) to handle the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WP plugins you usually have an empty action="" in a form, and handle it in the same function (by the way, as wordpress procedural code becomes very messy, it's better to write plugins using OOP), because, anyway plugins are loaded before any content is outputted in WP (this is the reason why writing ajax plugins is so easy in wp). So you can have everything structured like this:

```
function draw_form() {
    handle_submit();
?>
<div class="shk_location_form_holder">
    <span class="shk_loc_title"><?php echo $title; ?></span>
    <form mthod="post" action="">
        <input type="text" name="shk_inp_search_locations" id="shk_inp_search_locations" /><br>
        <div style="height:5px"></div>
        <input type="submit" Value="Search Locations" />
    </form>
</div>
<?
}

function handle_submit() {
    if(isset($_POST['shk_inp_search_locations']) && $_POST['shk_inp_search_locations'] == 'test') {
        echo 'you may want to end your program here, especially if it\'s ajax!';
        exit;
    }
}
```